# How to detect a specific object within range, on an AI?

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, unity-game-engine, detection

So I am making a replica of the game "Snake Pit" from the Spectrum. And you can move as your player and there are multiple AI controlled snakes. And I am trying to figure out how to make the snakeheads move to your location when they're right next to you. Here is my code that I want to implement it into.

```
public class SnakeController : MonoBehaviour {

public int maxSize;
public int currentSize;
public GameObject snakePrefab;
public Snake Head;
public Snake Tail;
public Vector2 nextPos;
public int NESW;
int Random;
float lineTimer;
int NESWTemp;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating("TimerInvoke", 0, .3f);
    lineTimer = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2.5f);
    currentSize = 1;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    lineTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (lineTimer <= 0)
    {
        ComChangeD();
        lineTimer = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2.5f);
    }
}

void TimerInvoke()
{
    Movement();
    if(currentSize >= maxSize)
    {
        TailFunction();
    }
    else
    {
        currentSize++;
    }
}

void Movement()
{
    GameObject temp;
    nextPos = Head.transform.position;

    if(nextPos.y > 3.22)
    {
        NESW = 2;
    }

    else if (nextPos.y < -4.42)
    {
        NESW = 0;
    }

    else if (nextPos.x < -8.2)
    {
        NESW = 1;
    }

    else if (nextPos.x > 7.7)
    {
        NESW = 3;
    }

    switch (NESW)
    {
        case 0:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x, nextPos.y + 0.32f);
            break;
        case 1:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x + 0.32f, nextPos.y);
            break;
        case 2:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x, nextPos.y - 0.32f);
            break;
        case 3:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x - 0.32f, nextPos.y);
            break;
    }

    temp = (GameObject)Instantiate(snakePrefab, nextPos, transform.rotation);
    Head.SetNext(temp.GetComponent<Snake>());
    Head = temp.GetComponent<Snake>();
    return;
}

void ComChangeD()
{
    NESWTemp = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3);
    if (NESW == 0)
    {
        switch (NESWTemp)
        {
            case 0:
                NESW = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                NESW = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                NESW = 3;
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (NESW == 1)
    {
        switch (NESWTemp)
        {
            case 0:
                NESW = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                NESW = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                NESW = 3;
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (NESW == 2)
    {
        switch (NESWTemp)
        {
            case 0:
                NESW = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                NESW = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                NESW = 3;
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (NESW == 3)
    {
        switch (NESWTemp)
        {
            case 0:
                NESW = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                NESW = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                NESW = 2;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: normally the logic in these games is whereever the AI is, take 1 step closer to the player character.. wherever it is..

Comment: @BugFinder Well there are multiple snakes and that would make the game too hard, I wouldn't mind testing and tweaking that though. Can you perhaps help me with that? But that aside this function is just there so that the snakes will kill the player if they're next to them. Now they're just going places and don't really care about the Player.

Comment: I do not know what that snake game is but why not use colliders?

Comment: @AleksaRistic As in make a box collider around the snake head with an is trigger?

Comment: Yea. Is it 2d or 3d game?

Comment: @AleksaRistic it's an 2D game, you can look up "Snake Pit Spectrum" on Google for a clear image of what I am trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create empty gameobject under snake head and call it 'DetectRange' or something like that. Then set it's width and height in inspector to the width and height of range you want your snake to follow player. So if player enter that range, snake will start following. Then you can set tag of player object to "Player" or something like that (that is on the top of inspector). Then you attach script to the `DetectRange` and inside it you do:

```
public GameObject playerObject; //Drag player gameobject in inspector
private float snakeSpeed = 1.0f;


void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.Tag == "Player") //Check if player entered collider
    {
        playerObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(playerObject.transform.position, col.gameObject.position, snakeSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This will definitely solve my problem!